# Can't connect to L2TP IPsec VPN from Windows 10 but it works with macOS High Sierra

Tags: windows, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

I am trying to connect from a Windows 10 client to an Ubiquiti EdgeRouter VPN, I went through the instructions on https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/204950294-EdgeRouter-L2TP-IPsec-VPN-Server but whenever I try to connect to the VPN I get the following:

***Can't connect to 
The L2TP connection attempt failed because the security layer could not negotiate compatible parameters with the remote computer.***

I did some research and changed the VPN security properties to allow Microsoft CHAP Version 2 (MS-CHAP v2) and also Challenge Handshake Authentication Protocol (CHAP) but it didn't seem to make a difference at all.

At the same time I have no problems whatsoever to connect from a macOS High Sierra client. So my guess is that there is something wrong on the client side (Windows VPN settings)? Can anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

That error message probably means that there is some level of connection between Windows and the Ubiquiti but they failed to find a common encryption method. For phase1 (key exchange) Windows (version 1803) is proposing the following encryption methods (in this priority order):

1. SHA1 + AES-CBC-256 + ECP384
2. SHA1 + AES-CBC-128 + ECP256
3. SHA1 + AES-CBC-256 + MODP2048
4. SHA1 + 3DES-CBC + MODP2048
5. SHA1 + 3DES-CBC + MODP1024

For phase2:

1. SHA1 + AES-CBC-256
2. SHA1 + AES-CBC-128

Make sure the Ubiquiti can accept one of these proposals so try to set the phase1 and phase2 proposals on the Ubiquiti to something like this.

```
set vpn ipsec ike-group FOO0 lifetime 86400
set vpn ipsec ike-group FOO0 proposal 1 dh-group 14
set vpn ipsec ike-group FOO0 proposal 1 encryption aes256
set vpn ipsec ike-group FOO0 proposal 1 hash sha1
set vpn ipsec esp-group FOO0 lifetime 43200
set vpn ipsec esp-group FOO0 pfs disable
set vpn ipsec esp-group FOO0 proposal 1 encryption aes128
set vpn ipsec esp-group FOO0 proposal 1 hash sha1
```

I would also enable NAT-Traversal too:

```
set vpn ipsec nat-traversal enable
```

I do not really know Ubiquiti but maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, but with a Cisco Meraki. Was working fine until my laptop upgraded to the 1803 build. I bet you have the same build. It was recently pushed out. Doesn't seem to matter what you do - there's something now wrong with L2TP.

If you're still on build 1709, then you need to add a firewall rule to allow ports 500, 1701, 4500 UDP/TCP both in and out.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd458955(v=ws.10)

Comment: Unfortunately disabling the firewall or opening the ports on the Windows client doesn't help either. I am still on Windows 10 1709.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is a bug in Windows 10 built-in VPN client. I have two almost identical VPN servers running SoftEther. VPN connection to the first one had no problems since I remember (using SSTP). The second VPN connection on the same Windows PC to a VPN server almost identically configured and hosted by the same provider in the same network - when connecting via SSTP, I could read from server log that Windows client did not accept, or offer, MSCHAP v2 for authentication.
Nothing could solve the problem until one day I tried to modify the Windows client to use L2TP/IPSec with PSK. It connected instantly. Then I just changed the configuration in Windows back to SSTP and it works like breeze ever since.